# JQuesr AJAX processing image problem

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page using jQuery flot plugin to draw line chart and works well. Now I want to improve it. When the js draws chart it will appear a processing image then display the chart.
The code of drawing is like:

```
$(function () {    
            $.plot($("#chart"), [ oneday ]);
        });
```

Div with image:

```
<div id="wait">
        <img src='wait.gif'/>
    </div>
```

There is no problem of these. But when I write code like this:

```
$(function () {    
        $("#chart").ajaxStart(function(){
               $("#wait").css("display","block");
              });
        $("#chart").ajaxComplete(function(){
                $("#wait").css("display","none");
              });
        $.plot($("#chart"), [ oneday ]);
    });
```

There is no image load. Could someone tell me why?

Comment: Tip: Use $("#wait").hide() and $("#wait").show() to change show/hide your div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `ajaxStart` and `ajaxComplete` is only called if ajax request start or complete. jqPlot don't use ajax requests. The jqPlot draws the plots on the client side.

```
    $("#wait").show();
    $.plot($("#chart"), [ oneday ]);
    $("#wait").hide();
```

Comment: thanks for your code, probably is the chart drawed too fast, there is no image displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the data isn't being requeste by Ajax. So this should work:

```
    $("#wait").css("display","block");
    $.plot($("#chart"), [ oneday ]);
    $("#wait").css("display","none");
```

Hope this helps. Cheers